# Read Settings properties (C#) in a Windows service with Windows server 2008

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows-server-2008, settings

I can´t start a windows service in Windows Server 2008 because of reading Settings properties. It can be a little strange but if I quit just the code of Settings.Default.myProperty the service intalled correctly.

Obviously the same service intalled in Windows 7 works fine with the Settings.Default.. so Im thinking the problem is Windows Server.

any ideas?

thank you

Comment: Make sure Service.exe.config exists in the service installed location, and its accessible for the service user.

Comment: Yes, this file is in the service location and its accesible because I can create a FileStream in write mode of this file but... then I tried to load this same file with XDocument and the service didnt start as same as the Setting.. and also I can´t capture any exception.. the service just stop.  I cant do any debugging because is a remote machine.. I was thinking maybe is something related with the framework.. but i installed the .net framework 4 extended..

Answer (score 0):

Could be a permission problem.
Make sure that you are installing the service as Administrator.
The installation log could also give you a hint on what is causing it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Server the .NET Framework 3.5 is disabled by default. I had installed the Framework 4 but is not enough. When I enabled the framework everything works like a charm.